# NameError: name 'tls' is not defined using plotly for Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

I am trying to run the [example](https://plot.ly/matplotlib/subplots/) provided by plotly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import plotly.plotly as py
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax1.plot([1,2,3,4,5], [10,5,10,5,10], 'r-')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
ax2.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16], 'k-')
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax3.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,10,100,1000], 'b-')
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224)
ax4.plot([1,2,3,4], [0,0,1,1], 'g-')


plt.tight_layout()
fig = plt.gcf()
plotly_fig = tls.mpl_to_plotly( fig )
plotly_fig['layout']['title'] = 'Simple Subplot Example Title'
plotly_fig['layout']['margin'].update({'t':40})
plot_url = py.plot(plotly_fig, filename='mpl-simple-subplot')
```

and I am having the following error:

> NameError: name 'tls' is not defined

I tried to google it and the results are irrelevant with my problem.

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: `import plotly.tools as tls`

Comment: why would the documentation on that page not include that import in their code samples? That seems like a miss on their part?

Comment: Can you people explain to me why you negatively rate me?

Comment: @DimKoim Never assume you know who downvoted you. It happens for many reasons. Unfortunately a lot of people will never comment on why they downvoted you.

Comment: @idjaw Indeed, but I would like to know why. I find it unfair being downvoted right now.

Comment: @DimKoim I'm not disagreeing with you. I wonder the same thing when I've had some things downvoted in the past. It would nice to get that courtesy. Unfortunately, this is the reality we have to deal with. The anonymity is there for good reason.

Comment: @DimKoim I downvoted your question because it seems that you didn't made any effort to try to solve this issue yourself. It took me actually a second (really) to guess what `tls`is, just by CTRL+F in the page you provided.

Comment: @DimKoim you probably were downvoted by a drive by person that did not realize you had the link to the full example there.  generally to void that copy the code as YOU ran it into the post.   That way transcription errors can be noted to you.  I upvoted your question to try and balance out the downvotes.

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ First of all, thank you for responding. You are right, I just tried to google the error with no result.

Comment: @DimKoim Try to edit your question so I can remove my downvote

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by way of importing a module with the `tls` alias.  `import plotly.tools as tls` was used per the `matplotlib` documentation.